# SSRS Hide Field and Label

Tags: reporting-services

I have this basic formula that adds "Tel:" to the beginning of the text but I want to hide Tel: and the number if it's empty. How can I modify it to do this?

="Tel:" & Fields!nphone.Value

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a conditional function like this:

```
=IIf( Len(Fields!nphone.Value) > 0, "Tel:" & Fields!nphone.Value,  Nothing )
```